# treeview change place after checking node in the web application

Tags: asp.net

i have an asp.net treeView. on node expanded i'm binding child nodes for the expanded node. But if i check the node and than expand it, the node and all it's child change there position and become like childs to the main node. when clicking again on the + it takes the right place. Any idea on how to solve it!!!

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnl_tree_testplan" CssClass="pnl_treeview" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="treeview_testplan" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:TreeView ID="testPlanTreeView" runat="server" OnLoad="Tree_TestPlan_Load" OnTreeNodeExpanded="Tree_TestPlan_Node_Expanded"
                                            OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="TestPlan_Treeview_TreeNodeCheckChanged">
                                        </asp:TreeView>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </asp:Panel>
            .pnl_treeview
            {
              Height:410px;
              border-width:1px;
              border-color:Blue;
              min-width:260px;
              width:100%;
              font-family:Calibri;
              font-size:small;
              color:Black;           
             }
```

Comment: Kindly add your code for reference of the question

Comment: What browser does this happen in?

Answer (score 0):

If it's "jumping up and down" in Firefox (esp.) when you hover over the nodes, try this CSS fix:

```
<div id="idTreeView">
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
            HoverNodeStyle-Height="0" Font-Bold="true" ImageSet="BulletedList">
        <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        <ParentNodeStyle VerticalPadding="0px" Font-Bold="True"
            Font-Underline="false"  />
        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
        <NodeStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="8pt" CssClass="sitelink"
            ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" 
            VerticalPadding="0px" />
    </asp:TreeView>

    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
</div>

div#idTreeView img
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

div#idTreeView div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

div#idTreeView .sitelink a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Irish But in my case its jumping left to right..Can u please post the answer for the above

Comment: Can you try and re-create this in jsfiddle.net so that we have an opportunity to actually help you resolve this? View source for the generated markup, then recreate that in jsfiddle.

Comment: I did it, in the result box it is showing the same output i get when i view in browser

Comment: Can you give us the jsfiddle link??